# Do I have to use webflows?

Tags: grails

I want to collect the data for a domain class over a few forms. I'd like to initialise an instance of the domain, carry it through the form pages (assigning the collected data to the properties of the instance) and save the instance after the last form is completed successfully.

Is there a way to do this without webflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this without webflows?

You can use `hidden` fields to accomplish this. But I may prefer you to use Webflows.

Here are some advantages of using Webflows:

1)You got two new scopes `flow` and `conversation` allows you to store variables, which are accessed within your flow

2)You have simple DSL to keep things tidy

3)Since there is a `flow` scope, you can do something like this:

```
 flow.someThing = new YourClassName(params) //places object in flow scope
```

**Keep in Mind:**

1)If you use flow-scoped objects your class need to be implemented `Serializable` class.

2)And from Grails 1.2, you need to install `Webflow` plugin explicitly. Document says this:

> From Grails 1.2 onwards Webflow is no longer in Grails core, so you
>   must install the Webflow plugin to use this feature: grails
>   install-plugin webflow

(see [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#webflow)).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of all the advantages of webflows (even though I am having data binding trouble, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861667/data-binding-issues-with-webflows), I was just wondering if there is a nice way of doing this without webflows. Your suggestion of hidden fields would work but as you said, webflows is preferable.

Comment: Grails webflow is so buggy that its almost useless for complex flows

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Ant's comment, you could use the `session`, but storing a non-domain object or a simple Map.  This will definitely lead to a lot of extra complexity, and the webflows *do* provide a lot of protection against accidental back-buttons, etc.

Rough idea:

in `grails-app/domain`

```
class Widget {
    String name
    int id

    // constraints, etc
}
```

in `grails-app/controllers`

```
class WidgetCommand {
    // setup your command
}
class WidgetController {
    def savePage1 = { WidgetCommand cmd ->
        // validate, etc
        def widget = session.tempWidget ?: [:]
        widget.putAll(cmd.properties)
        session.tempWidget = widget
        [widget: widget]
    }
    def savePage2 = { WidgetCommand cmd ->
        // etc
    }
    def savePage3 = {
        // or something similar here
        def finalWidget = new Widget(session.tempWidget)
        finalWidget.save()
    }
}
```

You could try storing an actual domain object directly in memory, but I believe that will automatically be saved at session close if you are editing the object (as opposed to new ones), and you'll have to re-link it to the Hibernate session.